# Should I use sugar soap or denatured alcohol to clean nicotine from painted walls?

Tags: walls, cleaning, paint, product-recommendation

I'd like to clean nicotine off of painted walls, but I'm not sure if I should use [sugar soap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugar_soap), or [denatured alcohol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denatured_alcohol) (methylated spirits).
Which would do a better job all-around, specifically for cleaning nicotine off of painted walls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found that some [Trisodium phosphate](http://www.dap.com/product_details.aspx?BrandID=90&SubcatID=17) works great for this.  Just mix some up in a bucket and use a sponge, and it should pull the nicotine right off, leaving the paint.  I'd definitely advise testing it in a small area first, but I've used it for this exact purpose before.

Comment: Thanks. i'm not sure why but someone edited my title to remove where I specifically indicated that sugar soap is a Trisodium phosphate equivalent.

Comment: @skybreaker - Yes, I noticed that after I posted my answer and checked out sugard soap (hadn't heard of it before).  I suppose I'd still recommend that particular product because I know it's worked before, but I would imagine the equivalent should work similarly.  As long as you test it in some small area first you should be fine.  Good luck!